# In a sentence, would I say, "Becoming part of", or "Becoming a part of"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I need this for a poem assignment! Please help would be greatly appreciated... we are all english-language-learners, regardless of whether it is our first language or not!

Comment: What I meant was that english is my first language, but it is still a lifelong process of learning!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently both are acceptable. Here is [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=becoming%20a%20part%20of%20%2Cbecoming%20part%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbecoming%20a%20part%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecoming%20part%20of%3B%2Cc0) results

As you can see "becoming part of" is much more common in usage.